The Gross Purchase Revenue figures between Google Play Console and Google Analytics 4 do not match
Discrepancy in Gross Purchase Revenue Between Google Play Console and Google Analytics 4
We have observed a discrepancy in the Gross Purchase Revenue figures reported by Google Play Console and Google Analytics 4. This inconsistency is affecting our ability to accurately analyze our app's financial performance. Below is a detailed explanation of the issue:
Overview of the Problem
Google Play Console: This platform provides comprehensive data on app downloads, user demographics, and revenue generated from in-app purchases and subscriptions.
Google Analytics 4 (GA4): This tool offers insights into user behavior, engagement, and conversion tracking within the app, including purchase events and revenue data.
Discrepancy Details
Gross Purchase Revenue: The total revenue generated from all purchases before any deductions, such as taxes, fees, or refunds.
The figures reported by Google Play Console and GA4 for Gross Purchase Revenue are not aligning, showing significant differences that cannot be accounted for by typical variations such as currency conversion or reporting delays.
I have tried collecting gross purchase revenue data by month starting from oct-2023 to may-2024 and compare both data month-on-month.

We have a similar issue. Did you manage to solve the problem?​
